# Can't get jQuery UI radio buttons working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to setup some [jQuery UI radio buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) but it's not working.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnSuh/)

HTML

```
<div id="type_radios">
    <input type="radio" value="option_a" name="note_type" id="note_type_option_a"/><label for="note_type_option_a">a</label>
    <input type="radio" value="option_b" name="note_type" id="note_type_option_b"/><label for="note_type_option_b">b</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#type_radios").buttonset();
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works, you just aren't including the stylesheet for jQuery UI (and in this case there's just no visual change without it), for example:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
```

[Here's your updated fiddle, stylesheet included, working :)](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vnSuh/1/)